# Format document in Visual Studio to insert braces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to "Format document" in Visual Studio to insert braces around single-statement blocks for C# code?  For example this:

```
if (x)
    y();
```

... would become something like:

```
if (x) { y(); }
```

The auto formatting seems to deal with indentation but not this brace insertion.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have **resharper** you can configure it to force braces depending on your criteria.
Than in the existing code press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, it will format whole file. Or select just part of the code, in this case resharper will format just selection

P.S. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> opens clean up dialog. You can configure cleanup options.

[image]

Comment: Yes, Resharper will completely reformat your code based on what you decide for those things. The tricky part is define the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there seems to be something built-in to Visual Studio to do this.

If you go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> New Lines` and make sure that you have `Place open braces on new lines for control block` checked.

Then, go to your document and use the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, this should reformat your document and add the curly braces.

Comment: I don't see a `Place open braces on new lines for open block` option.

Comment: Sorry, I meant control block, incorrectly copied the text. Updated my answer.

Comment: OK.  I tried this in VS 2012 and 2013, and it just plain doesn't work.  It doesn't insert any braces.  As far as I can tell the answer is wrong.

Comment: doesn't work for me either. would really need that feature

Answer (score 1):

I gave a vote to Gimly's answer as it is pretty much correct.  These things change over time of course.  I would have added a comment but I wanted to paste in some images.  Location of settings in VS2019 is at:
[image]

Uncheck the appropriate check boxes and select OK.

The shortcut key did not work, which is a shame because, I love them!  This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2022) suggests that you use
CTRL-K, CTRL-E or, you use the broom icon:

[image].

Neither option worked for me perhaps because, that is not the intention, given the list of options.  However, if you mark and cut all your code and then, paste the code back into the file, the new standard is adopted.